# java.lang.ClassDeNotFoundException:org.Hibernate.Exception SpringBoot with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

This is my pom.xml file.
The error i am getting is:
"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.bookstore</groupId>
<artifactId>bookstore</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>bookstore-angular</name>
<description>Web services for bookstore</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>



<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security </artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> 


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The error i get arose after i added some model classes with javax.persistence mappings

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these dependencies to the dependencies section of your pom :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: had tried that already...i think there is some conflict between different versions of the hibernate core and hibernate entity manager since they come under more than one dependency already added.

Comment: then you can try to delete .m2 folder and re-update pmaven project.

Comment: try to add dependency with version:

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.7.Final</version>
</dependency>`

and

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.7.Final</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Check transient dependencies. In my opinion, there is the conflict between eclipse.persistence and hibernate, but need to check

Comment: If you are not using anything specific from the eclipse package use the Hibernate libs directly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the `org.eclipse.persistence` version?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0-RC1</version>
</dependency>
```

Check in [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/javax.persistence)